# Can connect to server on the university network with ethernet but not with wifi

Tags: server, wireless, xrdp

In my lab, we set a dell server with the idea to connect via wifi to it. The server is located on the university and connect to the Internet with ethernet, using an static ip.

The server is running Linux server and i'm using windows 10 on my laptop. I set up to xrdp remote desktop and to ssh to connect to it. I can be connected and use the server when my laptopis connected with ethernet, but it is not possible with wifi, which was the main point  of the server. This is the same for xrdp and ssh, i can connect with ethernet but not with wifi.

I'm really lost since this is the first time that I set up a remote connection. I have not clue what the problem could be.

Thanks for your answers!

PS: The network is eduroam.

Comment: Can you make any network connection at all through your wifi? If so verify that the wifi device IP address is on the same subnet as the ethernet device IP. Is the server firewall accepting only a specific IP range?

Comment: The version of ubuntu is 18.04. I forgot to mention that xrdp is running with xfce.

Comment: Stephen, yes i have internet connection with wifi. How can i verified the last to questions ?

Comment: I believe he meant network connection, not necessarily internet. Some wifi routers create "isolated" wifi networks for safety reasons, specially those used in public locations.